# Problema con método Get en HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Estoy trabajando con la estructura `HashMap <Empresa, HashMap<String,Double>>`.

Tengo creada la clase empresa con método equals, compareTo, constructores...

Bueno el problema que tengo es que puedo insertar dos veces la misma empresa.

Un ejemplo, estoy leyendo datos de un fichero y voy creando las empresas sobre la marcha, pues bien, si creo empresa1 y la añado al HashMap, si continuo leyendo el archivo y vuelvo a crear de nuevo empresa1 y hago un get me devuelve null.

Me duplica la empresa, creo que es porque al crearla dos veces la referencia es distinta, pero esto se debería solucionar con el método equals ¿no?

El formato del archivo de texto es el siguiente:

> ```
> Contaminante1 A 5 8
> Contaminante2 A 5 8
> Contaminante2 A 6 8
> ```

El código es este, utilizo un scanner para leer la linea:

```
auxEmpresa = new Empresa(items[1],"",items[2]);
HashMap<String, Double> auxDemanda = demanda.get(auxEmpresa);

if(auxDemanda == null){
    System.out.println("Existe la empresa");
}else{
    System.out.println("No Existe la empresa aun");
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la clave para el HashMap?

Comment: Perdón olvidé pegar la estructura es esta: HashMap<Empresa, HashMap<String,Double>>

Comment: Deberias añadir el codigo asi como los datos que introduces

Comment: Has sobreescrito el método `hashCode`?

Comment: En el get antes de evaluar el equals evalua el hashCode (para encontrar la posicion de almacenado) del objeto que le pasas, como este es dintinto del anterior nunca lo encuentra.

Comment: Gracias será el hashCode, estoy acostumbrado a los TreeMap y desconocía ese dato, me voy a poner a modificarlo. Gracias @Lithorell

Comment: Me podríais poner un ejemplo de como editar el HashCode, con el atributo nombre de empresa por ejemplo @Lithorell.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/

Comment: @Lithorell en el ejemplo que has pasado,
 public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age;
        result = 31 * result + passport.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

result lo inicializa a 17 por alguna razón o es al azar?

Comment: Es azar, lo que tiene que hacer el hashcode es devolver un mismo valor para los mismos datos.

Comment: Perfecto todo solucionado gracias. Perdón es mi primer post como lo termino? @Lithorell

Comment: Puedes responderlo tú mismo para ayudar a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema. Pasado un par de días, podrás marcar la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en que el get antes de evaluar el equals evalúa el hashCode (para encontrar la posición de almacenado) del objeto que le pasas, como este es distinto del anterior nunca lo encuentra. La solución es sobrescribir el hashCode y el método equals así no duplicará la clave.

Comment: No entiendo cómo ponen negativo a esta respuesta cuando es correcta. HashMap necesita que sobre-escribas el método hashCode de los objectos que vas a utilizar como clave para saber si son iguales o no. Es importante recordar que también hay que sobreescribir el método equals en caso de que haya colisión de hash.